# javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException VS org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, jpa

I have this piece of code in a SpringBoot app. SpringBoot v1.5.14.RELEASE

```
    try {           
        bookAction result = bookActionRepository.save(bookAction);
    } catch (ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException e) {
        LOG.error (e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
```

But I have this exception in the application :

```
javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
```

Which difference there are between `OptimisticLockException` and `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` ? How do I know which exception will throw the application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` is used by `Spring ORM`, which is usually a part of `Spring Data JPA`, to indicate that OptimisticLocking failed so something changed data, that are to be commited in current transaction, in some other transaction.

After investigation of Spring ORM classes I found a class that might be your answer. Refer to [`JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException.html). The code for this exception is quite straightforward :

```
public class JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException extends ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException {

    public JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException(OptimisticLockException ex) {
        super(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }

}
```

Notice that it extends `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` and takes [`javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OptimisticLockException.html) and it invokes super contructor with message taken from `OptimisticLockException`. This is why you are seeing such exception message.

To answer your questions :

> What difference there are between OptimisticLockException and ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException ?

`OptimisticLockException` is specific to JPA which is an interface that is being implemented by many vendors (like Hibernate) and `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` is specific to `Spring ORM` which uses JPA/Hibernate internally.

> How do I know which exception will throw the application ?

If you are using `Spring ORM` you should catch `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` exception as this is a superclass of `HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException` and `JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException` so this one is most generic one and it's implementations will probably wrap other concrete exceptions (like shown above). Also remember that those exceptions are `RuntimeException` so you should explicitly catch them if you want to perform some processing based on them.